# TabView no Primefaces com Ajax

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Seguinte, estou com um pequeno problema, porém estou seguindo os mesmo passos do showcase do primefaces, mas sem sucesso.

Estou querendo que dispare um ajax toda vez q uma tab for selecionada, clicada. Dessa forma eu vou ter qual foi a tab selecionada e se o usuário pressionar f5, eu vou ter o valor da última tab armazenado em alguma variável e ele não irá para uma tab diferente, a não ser que ele click na nova tab.

Contudo, ao colocar o ajax com o event="tabChange" as tabs ficam travadas e mesmo clicando em outra tab não ocorre mudança.

Segue o código:

```
<p:tabView activeIndex="#{gerenciadorUsuarioView.controllerTabs}" id="tabViews">
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{gerenciadorUsuarioView.tabChange}" />
            <ui:include src="include/estagiario.xhtml"/>

            <ui:include src="include/gestores.xhtml"/>

        </p:tabView>
```

Na classe GerenciadorUsuarioView:

```
public void tabChange(TabChangeEvent event){
    this.controllerTabs = event.getTab().getId();
}
```

Já tentei passar no listener, depois do tabChange, um (event) tbm, mas sem resultado positivo.

Já fiz um leve debug e nem chama o método.

Será versão do primefaces? Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Não sei se ajuda, mas tive problemas com o TabView e não conseguia alterar o index pelo componente, tive que fazer uma função no bean para alterar o activeIndex http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167348/60946. Pode ser um bug do primefaces.