# Primefaces Dialog TabView

Tags: primefaces

Tenho um Dialog onde existe 2 tabviews, clico para exibir o dialog e alterno entre as abas, apos fechar se retorno ao TabView ele retorna com a ultima aba visitada sendo que preciso que ele retorno a primeira aba. Já tentei com activeIndex, ele funciona a primera vez, mas se fechar e retornar ele novamente exibe com a ultima aba visitada.

Sugestões?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Estou com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Só pra eu entender, você perguntou pra você mesmo se já resolveu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode tentar da seguinte maneira: crie um método para abrir a `dialog` e setar o valor do `activeIndex` diretamente pelo bean.

```
public void abrirDialog() {
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent componente = viewRoot.findComponent("idTabView");
    TabView tabView = (TabView) componente;
    tabView.setActiveIndex(0); //Vai abrir a primeira aba
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(componente.getClientId());
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('widgetVarDialog').show();");
}
```

Comment: Estou tendo um NullPointer ao chamar o método para exibir como explicou. Tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo ?

Comment: O Meu problema esta aqui que não encontra o componente.

Comment: @Jeremias Santos às vezes eu preciso usar um método auxiliar para buscar no ViewRoot, como vc informou. Normalmente, o findComponent já é suficiente. Obrigado pela informação.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver com mais este método:

```
public UIComponent findComponent(final String id) {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
        final UIComponent[] found = new UIComponent[1];

        root.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {
            @Override
            public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent component) {
                if (component.getId().equals(id)) {
                    found[0] = component;
                    return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
                }
                return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
            }
        });

        return found[0];

    }
```