# p:Dialog p:tabView Reset

Tags: primefaces

Tenho um p:dialog onde dentro dele consta um p:tabView, o botão que aciona o Dialog possui um Action o qual chama um método para inicializar os dados da tela, porém ao abrir o Dialog, percorrer nas abas e acessar novamente o mesmo não retorna para a primeira aba, fica sempre selecionada com a ultima aba visitada.

Estou usando o:

```
< p:dialog header="Produto e Serviço" widgetVar="produtoServDialog" id="produtoServ-dialog" resizable="true" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true" height="90%" width="90%">

< p:tabView id="tabViewProdutos" dynamic="true" scrollable="true" prependId="false" cache="false" activeIndex="0">
```

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167348/60946

Comment: Obrigado darei sequencia pelo post de lá.